How to fix "ValueError: Channel is invalid" error when running GPIO code?
I am trying to set up DC motors on a Jetson Nano, using the RPi.GPIO library. However when I try to assign in1 = 35, in2 = 36, and en = 33, it gives me the error:

ValueError: Channel 35 is invalid

I have tried using other pins, but I am fairly new to this so I don't understand why my current setup isn't working. I have assigned in1 and in2 based on the pins connected to the ones labelled as such on the L298N motor driver I'm using.
